# R Data Frame Manipulation - Replacing Elements of df2 with the Corresponding Row from df1

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2`. I want to replace every element in `df2` with the corresponding row from `df1`. See below:

```
> df1
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  7 11 22 35 36 37
2  6 14 17 18 32 38
3  9 17 21 24 33 37

df2
V1 V2 V3
1  1 NA NA
2  2 NA NA
3  3 NA NA
4  1  2 NA
5  1  3 NA
6  2  3 NA
7  1  2  3
```

I can get pretty close to the desired output by using the following line of code: `df1[t(df2),]`, which generates the following output:

```
> df1[t(df2),]
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1     7 11 22 35 36 37
NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA
NA.1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2     6 14 17 18 32 38
NA.2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
NA.3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3     9 17 21 24 33 37
NA.4 NA NA NA NA NA NA
NA.5 NA NA NA NA NA NA
1.1   7 11 22 35 36 37
2.1   6 14 17 18 32 38
NA.6 NA NA NA NA NA NA
1.2   7 11 22 35 36 37
3.1   9 17 21 24 33 37
NA.7 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2.2   6 14 17 18 32 38
3.2   9 17 21 24 33 37
NA.8 NA NA NA NA NA NA 
1.3   7 11 22 35 36 37
2.3   6 14 17 18 32 38
3.3   9 17 21 24 33 37
```

However, I would like the output to retain the same amount of rows as `df2` (nrow = 7, ncol = 18) and to look like the below:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18]
[1,]    7   11   37   35   36   37   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[2,]    6   14   32   32   32   38   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[3,]    9   17   21   24   33   37   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[4,]    7   11   37   35   36   37    6   14   32    32    32    38    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[5,]    7   11   37   35   36   37    9   17   21    24    33    37    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[6,]    6   14   32   32   32   38    9   17   21    24    33    37    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[7,]    7   11   37   35   36   37    6   14   32    32    32    38     9    17    21    24    33    37
```

Comment: Images are not a good way of posting data (or code). [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` should be replaced by both `df1` and `df2`)

Comment: How about something like: `t(apply(df2, 1, function(x) t(df1[x,])))`?

Comment: Where do the `ncol = 18` from your desired output come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` to iterate over columns of `df2` and `sapply` to iterate over columns of `df1`, subset the values to get combined matrix in the end.

```
unname(do.call(cbind, lapply(df2, function(x) sapply(df1, function(y) y[x]))))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18]
#[1,]    7   11   22   35   36   37   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#[2,]    6   14   17   18   32   38   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#[3,]    9   17   21   24   33   37   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#[4,]    7   11   22   35   36   37    6   14   17    18    32    38    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#[5,]    7   11   22   35   36   37    9   17   21    24    33    37    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#[6,]    6   14   17   18   32   38    9   17   21    24    33    37    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#[7,]    7   11   22   35   36   37    6   14   17    18    32    38     9    17    21    24    33    37
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(7L, 6L, 9L), V2 = c(11L, 14L, 17L), V3 = c(22L, 
17L, 21L), V4 = c(35L, 18L, 24L), V5 = c(36L, 32L, 33L), V6 = c(37L, 
38L, 37L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), V2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), V3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```